# Automate Ngen in web application

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automation, jit, ngen

My team develops a web application using Entity framework 6. Recently I've read that installing ngen on Entity Frameqork dlls could help start up time by preventing the JIT of dlls.

My question might be silly:
If I run ngen on the dlls on my work station, is there any way to automatically run those ngen commands on my partners work station? Like some sort of script which I'm very unfamiliar with?

Moreover, is there any reason not to run Ngen on all of the application's dlls?